# Django - reload template after post request

Tags: django

My template does not reload immediately after hitting button for post request. But I know the request worked fine because if I load the page manually (with link) I can see it changed correctly. Any ideas? I understand the problem is in the render of post method...

```py
def profile(request, user):
    this_user = request.user
    profileuser = get_object_or_404(User, username=user)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=profileuser).order_by('id').reverse()
    followed = Follow.objects.filter(followed=profileuser)
    following = Follow.objects.filter(following=profileuser)
    all_followed = len(followed)
    all_following = len(following)
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)
    if request.GET.get("page") != None:
        try:
            posts = paginator.page(request.GET.get("page"))
        except:
            posts = paginator.page(1)
    else:
        posts = paginator.page(1)

    try:
        both_follow = Follow.objects.filter(followed=profileuser, following=request.user)
    except:
        both_follow == False

    context = {
        "posts": posts,
        "profileuser": profileuser,
        "all_followed": all_followed,
        "all_following": all_following,
        "both_follow": both_follow,
        "this_user": this_user,
    }

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "network/profile.html", context)

    if request.method == "POST":     
        if both_follow:
            both_follow.delete()   
            both_follow == False     
        else:
            f = Follow()
            f.followed = profileuser
            f.following = request.user
            f.save()
            both_follow == True
        return render(request, "network/profile.html", context)
```

And the html is:

```
<p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#followed">{{ all_followed }} Followers </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#following">{{ all_following }} Following </button>
</p>

{% if profileuser != this_user %}

    {% if both_follow %}
        <form action="{% url 'profile' profileuser %}" method="POST">   {% csrf_token %}
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">UnFollow</button>
        </form>
        
    {% else %}
        <form action="{% url 'profile' profileuser %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Follow</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to handle `if request.method == "GET"`, it is `GET` by default if you're not doing a `POST` request.

Also it is a good practice to do a `redirect` after `POST` and not reply with a rendered page containing the results, because the `POST` request can be resubmitted(which could lead to data duplication), by:

- reloading result page using Refresh/Reload browser button (explicit page reload, implicit resubmit of request);
- clicking Back and then Forward browser buttons (implicit page reload and implicit resubmit of request);
- returning back to HTML FORM after submission, and clicking Submit button on the form again (explicit resubmit of request)

So you can just redirect to your page after hitting `POST`.

Now i don't know how you named your url pattern for `profile` view, but presuming your **urls.py** are:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('network/profile/<int:user>/', views.profile, name='network_profile')
]
```

Your **views.py** would then look like:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse


def profile(request, user):
    this_user = request.user
    profileuser = get_object_or_404(User, username=user)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=profileuser).order_by('id').reverse()
    followed = Follow.objects.filter(followed=profileuser)
    following = Follow.objects.filter(following=profileuser)
    all_followed = len(followed)
    all_following = len(following)
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)
    if request.GET.get("page") != None:
        try:
            posts = paginator.page(request.GET.get("page"))
        except:
            posts = paginator.page(1)
    else:
        posts = paginator.page(1)

    try:
        both_follow = Follow.objects.filter(followed=profileuser, following=request.user)
    except:
        both_follow == False

    context = {
        "posts": posts,
        "profileuser": profileuser,
        "all_followed": all_followed,
        "all_following": all_following,
        "both_follow": both_follow,
        "this_user": this_user,
    }

    if request.method == "POST":     
        if both_follow:
            both_follow.delete()   
            both_follow == False     
        else:
            f = Follow()
            f.followed = profileuser
            f.following = request.user
            f.save()
            both_follow == True

        return redirect(reverse('network_profile')) # We redirect to the same view

    return render(request, "network/profile.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the solution using redirect to the same page:

```
return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```